# Partitioning tables based on a range of date with and deleting them efficiently

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I need to partition my table `devices` such that I can easily drop partitions that are no more required. This is based on the subscription for the particular user inserting the devices. My plan is to:

1. All devices for users with subscription for 7 days goes into the table meant for 7 days, say devices_7d. Similarly, devices for 14 days goes to devices_14d.
2. There are 22 different periods of subscriptions - 7d, 14d, 30d, etc. up to 3 years. Hence, there would be as many partitions.
3. Based on the days, drop the table every X days. This means, I drop the table devices_7d after every 7 days, and then create a new table with the same name - making sure the new devices (with a subscription for 7 days) is inserted in this new table

This is mostly done to make sure the space used up by the devices is cleaned up, and usable as soon as they are removed (hence the choice of dropping the table).

My question is is this a good solution or are there better solutions to tackle this problem?

And more importantly, is there a way this (Point 3) can be done (or configured) automatically in Postgres. That is, we instruct it to drop the table and create a new one every 7 days (and likewise for different subscription periods) ?

Note: I'm using Postgres 10

Comment: This doesn't really work when I subscribe near the end of that week - then my subscription won't last 7 days, but only until you drop the table the next time. You need to store the date when the subscription will expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PostgreSQL v10 with partitioning. Upgrade to at least v12.

There are no automatic ways to create and drop partitions; you will have to schedule it using external tools like `cron` or extensions like `pg_timetable`.

I question your partitioning scheme.  If you delete and re-create the partition every 7 days, then you cannot have seven-day subscriptions that start in the middle of that period.

If I were you, I would range partition the table on the subscription **expiry** date. Then it is easy to drop all expired subscriptions in a single `DROP TABLE`, regardless of the subscription period.

Comment: This cannot handle subscriptions that start in the middle, so not a solution indeed (what I proposed) . But if we partition on expiry date - the one that get's added in the middle will still go to its own table based on the expiry date - how could I then drop all expired subscriptions in a single `DROP TABLE`? And also it means I could then have around 1095 tables (3 * 365 days) . Isn't it a large number - and this could then potentially affect reads (say if I am trying to get a single device - it then has to scan 1095 tables) ?

Comment: Ah, no I understand what you mean by the single DROP, you just need to delete the table on that day, as all entries in that would expire on that day.

Comment: You don't need a partition per day. You can have one per week. There is no harm in keeping expired subscriptions sitting around for a couple of days, right?

Comment: Actually we cannot do that, as in we shouldn't keep them for more than a day. Although most subscriptions are between 0-30 days while only very few (<1%) are more than that. Wonder if we can optimize the number of tables in this case.

Comment: You could keep them, but exclude them with a `WHERE` condition in your queries. Or is it a legal matter? And with PostgreSQL v12 or above, you should be OK with ~1000 partitions.

Comment: We have decided to go to pg14. Weekly partitioning should work , we could just delete daily but drop the tables weekly.   That should also reduce the number of tables to around 100. Is it also possible to have weekly partition for the next 4 weeks and 1 for the rest ? Then I could also have a sub partition (hash) for the user

Comment: Then you would have to move the data from daily partitions to weekly ones regularly, which is of course possible, but perhaps painful.

Comment: Is it an idea then to use the default partition for the rest . That’s never dropped, but record only deleted. We then have 4 partitions (if weekly) or 30 (if daily) and 1 default partition.

Comment: Any solution that means deleting or moving lots of rows between partition is not great, I'd say.

Comment: In this case though I’m not moving any rows ? Just that I will be deleting rows from the default table which is expected to have far less records anyway . For the other partitions , I just drop the table .

Comment: If you end up deleting lots of rows rather than dropping a table, you are not using partitioning correctly.

Comment: Ok , will try to change that architecture. One unrelated question though - but related to partitioning , if I partition first by user Id and then sub partition by date , would it help to have a composite index on the device id and user id, considering that most queries will be with both device id and user id? As I read we shouldn’t have index on a partitioned column , but not sure about the composite index.